# Has this functor been studied?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ct.category-theory, differential-equations

Let $\mathbb{O}$ be the category where the objects are $n$-manifolds, and the morphisms are almost-everywhere smooth cobordisms along with almost-everywhere smooth partial differential equations on those cobordisms. I think that we need to allow almost-everywhere smoothness for composition to be well-defined, if there is a way of getting around this, I would be interested to know.

Let $\mathbb{R}$ be the category where the objects are again $n$-manifolds, but the morphisms between $S$ and $T$ are relations $R \subseteq C^1(S) \times C^1(T)$.

Finally, the functor that I am interested in takes a differential equation $E$ on a cobordism $C$ to the relation $F(C,E)$ that is defined to be the set of restrictions of solutions of $E$ to the source and target of the cobordism.

This functor is interesting because it is a first step to understanding open systems with continuous boundary, as an extension of Baez's work on open systems like electrical circuits or petri nets that have discrete boundary (sets of terminals or sets of species).

Comment: Could you be more specific about the PDEs? Are they on functions or on sections of some vector bundles that come along with the data? Are they elliptic or have some other nice analytic properties (that e.g. ensure that $F(C,E)$ carries some information)?